# What type of antenna are these?

Tags: antenna

On top of a mountain in south Salt Lake City, Utah there are many antennas.

What are these curly ones?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a vertical array of circular polarized antennas, each half element as half turnstile and half traveling wave used for the circular phasing.

Comment: Circularly polarized, yes. I didn't think about that. But what do you mean about the traveling wave part?

Comment: Traveling wave may be the wrong term.  But I wasn't sure what to call a widely spaced (non-coax) phasing delay line that might be part of each antenna element.